# Magento 2 Order Summary not showing up on checkout shipping tab on IE browser 11

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, customize

I have customized the checkout_index_index.xml file to display the order summary on the checkout shipping tab as Magento 2 by default doesn't display it.

Here is my customization on the checkout_index_index.xml added after line 387:

```
<item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
    <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
            <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

This works on Chrome and firefox (refer screenshot[image] but not in IE 11.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: have you got any solutions?

Comment: @AjayPatel No, I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: I fetch this issue in magento 2.2.6 also